# テーブルレイアウトのアルゴリズムの仕様は、どこで確認できますか？

Tags: html, css

## 背景

HTMLのtable要素の列幅が、CSSで指定した`width`によって、どう変わるかを確認していました。

たとえば、以下のtable要素のwidthは、col要素に指定したwidthと矛盾しています（`200 != 200 + 50`）。
このHTMLをブラウザで確認すると、table要素のwidthは250pxでした。

```
<table style="width:200px;">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:200px;"><col style="width:50px;">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1A</td>
            <td>1B</td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSSは以下の通りです。

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed; /* 列幅を固定レイアウトにする */
}
td, th {
  /* td/th要素でwidthを指定したときと、col要素で指定したときの幅が同じになるようにする */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table,td,th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

## 質問

なぜ、上記のような動きをになるかを、HTML,CSSの仕様で確認したいです。
どのページを確認すれば良いですか？

Google検索したところ、仕様らしいページが見つかりました。
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-tables-3/#computing-column-measures
https://drafts.csswg.org/css3-tables-algorithms/Overview.src.htm

しかし、

- 前者は、「Not Ready For Implementation」
- 後者は、「This document is obsolete.」

と書いてあり、どちらも今のブラウザの仕様を表しているようには、思えませんでした。

## 追記の質問

以下のtableは列幅が150pxでした。これはすべてのセルの中で、最大の幅が適用されています。

```
 <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:50px;">1A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:150px;">2A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:100px;">3A</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

しかし、CSS2の仕様には、

> Otherwise, a cell in the first row with a value other than 'auto' for the 'width' property determines the width for that column.

と書いてありました。
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#fixed-table-layout

これはどう解釈すればよいでしょうか？先頭行のセルが列幅を決めているようには見えませんでした。

Comment: 追記部分のご質問はタイトルの「テーブルレイアウトのアルゴリズムの仕様は、どこで確認できますか？」からやや離れているように見えます。新しく質問し直して頂くほうが、スッキリするかもしれません。

Comment: 追記の質問ですが、先頭行にある場合と違ってtable要素のwidthを50pxにすれば自動的には広がることはありません。余裕があればその範囲で幅を広げるということなので、困る人はいません。仕様のナイスな拡張だと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

table要素の幅は、`table-layout`の設定によって変わってきます。既定又は`auto`であれば、以下の図のように各列の幅が調整されて、table要素の幅は200pxとなります。

`table-layout`を`fixed`にすると、このケースでは`<colgroup>`で設定した幅になるので、table要素の幅は250pxとなります。質問で「table要素のwidthが250pxとなった」のは、質問に表示されている以外の所で`fixed`に設定しているためと思われます。

現在の`table-layout`の仕様は [CSS Level 2 (Revision 1)のtable-layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout) だと思われます。質問にあるように、CSS3については草稿（Working Draft）段階です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `table-layout:fixed`のときの話です。質問文にCSSを追記しました。

Answer (score 1):

[MDNのtable-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)では、[CSS Level 2 (Revision 1)のtable-layout の定義](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout)を仕様としているようです。

ただ、[CSS Level 2 (Revision 1)のtable-layout の定義](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout)内では、"Automatic table layout"について`Note. This may be defined in more detail in CSS3.`となっているため、概要のみ記載のようです。